# Trigger for Automate average after insert a row details like User Rate Average MSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to automate rateAvg for each row

```
userID pID rate1 rate2 rate3 rate4 rate5   rateCmmt     rateAvg     
42      24  2     4      3    4     1      Lorem ipsum     0
45      25  3     4      4    2     1      Lorem ipsum     0
```

Here my code that i tried.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `updateAVG`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `updateAVG` 
AFTER INSERT ON `tblrate` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE tblrate SET `rateAvg` = ((`rate1`+`rate2`+`rate3`+`rate4`+`rate5`)/5)
```

Comment: Why not just calculate the average on insert?

Answer (score 1):

You want a *before* insert trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `updateAVG`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `updateAVG` BEFORE INSERT ON `tblrate` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET new.rateAvg = (new.rate + new.rate2 + new.rate3 + new.rate4 + new.rate5) / 5;
END;
```

You could also just do this with a view:

```
create v_updateAVG as 
    select u.*, (u.rate + u.rate2 + u.rate3 + u.rate4 + u.rate5) / 5 as rateAvg
    from updateAVG;
```

Or, in MySQL 5.7.6+ as a generated column:

```
alter table updateAVG add rateAvg as ((rate + rate2 + rate3 + rate4 + rate5) / 5);
```

The advantage of these last two methods is that the average is always up-to-date, after both inserts and updates.

Comment: Error----------
#1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: @ApuHasan . . . That was a typo.  A "before" trigger should be defined as `before`, not `after`.

Comment: But want it with trigger within same table NOT VIEW.